# Learning about cross-browser compatibility

Tags: cross-browser, client-side

I have focussed on server side development for a few years and now I am branching out into client-side application construction.

I must say that I am finding it difficult to make the client-side application look the same across multiple browsers....

Are there any decent online resources that can aid the **faster** learning of cross-browser compatibility principles...

Answer (score 0):

For the HTML/CSS part, I find that if you follow the following two rules, things usually work out fairly well:

- Write standards-compliant, semantic HTML. Focus on semantically correct document structure first, then use CSS to lay it out the way you want. Only change the HTML if you feel you absolutely have to. Avoid layout patterns that are hard to get right with HTML and CSS, and if you have to, [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/) contains tons of articles about these things.
- Test in all the browsers. If you're serious about web development, you need a bunch of test setups; at the very least, I recommend you have these ready: Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 9 (this means you have to use virtual machines, as there is no way to realistically simulate different IE versions on the same OS install); Firefox 3.6 and 7 (or whatever the current version is); the most recent Google Chrome; a somewhat older Chrome or Chromium (I use chromium from debian); Opera (because it does not share any important components with any other browser). If you can afford a Mac, add FF/Mac and Safari to the mix. If you develop for mobile devices, you need to test on those as well - at least Android and iOS.

If you have to support older Internet Explorer versions (7 or, gasp, 6), then conditional comments are your friend - my usual strategy is to make a design that works on all the other browsers first, and then add one or more special style sheets in conditional comments (so that only IE loads them) that 'fix' things for these broken browsers.

For the javascript part, the sane thing to do is go with a framework that polishes the various pecularities away - jQuery is probably the most popular one at the moment.